# CSS Intellisense for files not in solution

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, resharper, web-essentials, resharper-8.0

Is there any way to include css/less files for intellisense purposes, but not have them in the solution / project (VS 2013)

I am using bower / gulp to manage my dependencies and inject them into my final html.
As such, I don't want to include my bower_components folder into my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using gulp or grunt for your build you might try something like this: http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/02/09/ensuring-intellisense-for-bower-packages-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=ensuring-intellisense-for-bower-packages-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: That's pretty much the approach that I took